# laravel ajax call in safari and on mobile methodNotFoundHttpException

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, safari

I'm having some issues on my application, I'm using laravel 4.2 framework. Everything seems to be working fine, except when I test it on safari and mobile phone

This is the ajax request that I make

`function couponAuth(data)
    {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'coupon/verify',
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
                if(response.status === 'fail')
                {
                    displayError(response.data.coupon[0]);
                }
                else{
                    $(location).attr('href',response.data.url);
                }
            },
            error: function(response){`

```
        }
    });
}
```

this is the route

`Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function(){
    Route::post('/coupon/verify',['uses' => 'AccessController@validate', 'as' => 'coupon-verify']);
});`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function couponAuth(data)
    {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({ 
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'coupon/verify',
                data: data,
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.status === 'fail')
                    {
                        displayError(response.data.coupon[0]);
                    }
                    else{
                        $(location).attr('href',response.data.url);
                    }
                },
                error: function(response){
                }
            });
        });
    }
```